# operator LIKE in SQL

Tags: sql

In case I have a field with the value `"Lucene Game Lucene"` and I'm looking for that document using the keyword "Game" I can't get that result using `*keyword` neither `keyword*` Who have any idea about this?

Comment: SQL uses `%` as it's placeholder for *any number of any character* - not `*` (that's the DOS placeholder)

Comment: `WHERE whatever LIKE "%game%"`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE field LIKE '%keyword%'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mySQL:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html

Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM pet WHERE name LIKE '%w%';
```